# A method to plot power consumption graph with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently doing a small bit of coding for my master's thesis, and decided to do it in python which I toyed around with during a project last year due to finding it quite pleasent to code in.

I'm writing a small model simulating a cryptosystem leaking power usage side channel information during an XOR operation, giving out a list of various power uses after computing different values. I'm looking to output the results in the form of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCncx.png) kind of graph , but am having trouble pinning down what exactly I need to do for it. In the end I hope to have a graph outputting the variations in power use as each key is compared through XOR to the constant key value. I'm sure my answer lies in matplotlib somewhere, it's just the type of graph I can't seem to find the method for.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the picture you provided, I think [plot()](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) satisfied your requirement. Following is a simple example:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
y = np.random.random_sample(len(x))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel('Power Point')
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

[image: example.png]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the examples given in [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html), because the lineplot type of graphs are supported and I checked and saw examples similar to what you need. Just click on any example plot to see the source code and how its done.

Side note: I'd also suggest investigating and studying `R` and `ggplot2` as IMO they are simpler to use for plotting and the resulting plots usually look nicer, which is especially important in a thesis paper.

Comment: If only I had more time I'd have definitely looked at R, but it's at a bit of late stage I'm afraid. Interesting though, I'll take it into consideration in future, thank you!  

I'm amazed I haven't seen that gallery, though to be honest my main search for a method to graph my results only began today. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with the answer, then you can "accept" it by ticking a mark on the left side of the answer :)

Comment: matplotlib plots can look quite nice if you put in the effort to customize them properly, though.